# Markdown ou Html para formatar as perguntas e respostas?

Tags: debate, suporte

Olá, sei que o *SOpt* suporta editar as perguntas com `html` e `markdown`, mas eu tenho 2 dúvidas:

- por que o *site* utiliza as duas e não apenas uma?(`html` ou `markdown`)
- Utilizar `html` não causa brechas de `XSS`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> por que o site utiliza as duas e não apenas uma? (HTML ou markdown)

Porque os desenvolvedores viram valor nisso, acham que um é melhor e outro ajuda um pouco mais.

> Utilizar HTML não causa brechas de XSS?

O site não aceita HTML, aceita apenas um subconjunto, então não dá para fazer XSS.

Espero não estar falando besteira, mas acho que teremos outra forma em breve.

Comment: "Por tabela" a pergunta acabou puxando o assunto das novidades. Por enquanto o que você vê no sistema é o que você tem na pergunta. ;)